# Input tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors

Tags: keras, keras-layer

```
Input tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found:
Tensor("my_layer/Identity:0", shape=(?, 10, 1152, 16), dtype=float32)
(missing Keras metadata).
```

Hi, I get this error when trying to take one layer's intermediate variable to use it as input to a parallel network. Such that one layer's intermediate variable will be input to the other network.

```
def call(self, inputs,  training=None):
    inputs_expand = K.expand_dims(inputs, 1)
    tensor_b = K.tile(inputs_expand, [1, 16, 1, 1])
    tensor_a = K.map_fn(lambda x: K.batch_dot(x, self.Weights, [2, 3]), elems=tensor_b)
    # I need this tensor_a
    # I tried many things but ended putting it to member variable.
    self.tensor_a = K.identity(inputs_hat)
    ....
```

outside when trying to build the parallel model I do this

```
a_model = models.Model([my_layer.tensor_a],[my_layer.c])
```

I could not find any good solution to this problem? How can I turn the tensor into `K.tensor`??